# Generic XML to Dataset

Tags: import, dataset, associations, xml

I am having trouble to transform XML data into a Mathematica Dataset of Associations. I want a dataset that follows the structure of the XML file with all its sublevels. Here is the example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Readconfig version="1.0">
  <LVL1>
  
    <LVL2 attribute="1">
        <LVL3>
            <LVL4 attribute="11">
                <LVL5 attribute="111"/>
                <LVL5 attribute="112"/>
                <LVL5 attribute="113"/>
                <LVL5 attribute="114"/>
            </LVL4>
        </LVL3>
    </LVL2>
    
    <LVL2 attribute="2">
        <LVL3>
            <LVL4 attribute="21">
              <LVL5 attribute="211"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="212"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="213"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="214"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="215"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="216"/>
            </LVL4>
            
            <LVL4 attribute="22">
              <LVL5 attribute="221"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="223"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="224"/> 
              <LVL5 attribute="225"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="226"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="227"/>
              <LVL5 attribute="228"/>
            </LVL4>
        </LVL3>
    </LVL2>
    
    <LVL2 attribute="3">
        <LVL3>
            <LVL4 attribute="31">
              <LVL5 attribute="311"/>     
            </LVL4>
        </LVL3>
    </LVL2>
    
  </LVL1>
 
</Readconfig>
```

I tried:

```
Dataset@Cases[myXMLdata, 
  XMLElement[_, attrs_, _] :> Association[attrs], Infinity]
```

but it only shows the Dataset of the lowest levels. Also note that the XML file might change structure and i dont want to hardcode any levels of the XML file.
Does anyone have a simple solution?

Comment: Some elements have attributes AND sub elements e.g.:  "{XMLElement["LVL2", {"attribute" -> "1"}, {XMLElement["LVL3",...." How do you want this represent in an association?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
xml = ImportString["the provided complete xml", "XML"];
```

Part 2 of the imported xml the actual data skipping the xml version and encoding. Then repeatedly apply a rule and convert to a dataset:

```
ds = xml[[2]] //
     ReplaceRepeated[XMLElement[tag : _String, attrs : _List, value : _List] :> 
       <|"tag" -> tag, "attributes" -> <|attrs|>, "value" -> value|>] //
     Dataset
```

this is the resulting dataset:

[image]

drill down to the value of the Readconfig tag:

[image]

drill down to the deepest level:

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Works very well!